# How to hide UITabbar and UINavigationBar at the top when UIView changes to LandscapeOrientation?

Tags: iphone, uiinterfaceorientation

I am using tabbarcontroller application with 4 tabs, each tab integrate with UInvaigationcontroller, when get in to detail page from first page, showing html text in UIWebview. when you do orientation to Landscape, need to hide tabbarcontroller and navigation controller from that particular page.

Regards

sri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the UINavigationController, in your rotate method (probably `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:`, use `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES`

for the UITabBarController its going to be a bit more application specific, depends on how it is all interlinked.